# Como hacer configuración del archivo hibernate.reveng para Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate

estoy haciendo una pequeña practica de Hibernate, pero al momento de querer configurar el archivo hibernate.reveng, no me sale ninguna conexión para poder usar la tabla de la base de datos, alguien tiene idea de por que me ocurre esto?

Dejo el XML que se me genero de hibernate.cfg.xml:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
   <session-factory>
     <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:sqlserver://localhost\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=Agenda</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">Macx</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">123456</property>
<property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect</property>
<property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
<property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```